# MSB4242: The SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run. Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

Unable to build my visual stuidio proj from command prompt. (Visual studio 2019 ,.net core )

> sourceanalyzer %MEMORY_TRANSLATION% -b %BUILDID%  -logfile 
>   %LOGFILE_TRANSLATION% msbuild myChatBot.sln
>   /t:Rebuild/p:Configuration=Debug/p:Platform="any cpu"

we are trying to run fortify scan on my code using the HP Fortify script/bat file, above line of code is  to build the sln from visual studio 2019 command prompt. Getting the error message as pasted below

> C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj : warning MSB4242: The SDK resolver
>   "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run. Illegal
>   characters in path. Project "C:\Users....\myprojVA.sln" (1) is
>   building "C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj" (2) on node 1 (Rebuild
>   target(s)). C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK
>   'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found. Done Building
>   Project "C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
>   C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj : warning MSB4242: The SDK resolver
>   "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run. Illegal
>   characters in path. Project "C:\Users....\myprojVA.sln" (1) is
>   building "C:\Users....\myprojVA.Tests.csproj" (3) on node 1 (Rebuild
>   target(s)). C:\Users....\myprojVA.Tests.csproj : error MSB4236: The
>   SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. Done Building
>   Project "C:\Users....\myprojVA.Tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) --
>   FAILED. Done Building Project "C:\Users....\myprojVA.sln" (Rebuild
>   target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj : warning MSB4242: The SDK resolver
>   "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run. Illegal
>   characters in path.
>
> C:\Users....\myprojVA.Tests.csproj : warning MSB4242: The SDK
>   resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run. Illegal
>   characters in path.

Any thoughts on why the SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you show us an excerpt from the project file's text? If the path is *actually* specified as `C:\Users....\myprojVA.csproj` then that looks a bit 'illegal' - but maybe that's just the error reporter abbreviating the path. An inspection of the `.csproj` file in text mode may resolve the issue.

Comment: Please check whether the path of the System variables which you config has errors and make sure that the path can access. Also, if you set  the path, please make sure there are no extra spaces in the input path like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd ;`and the `;` has been preceded by an extra space.Besides, if you run the command "msbuild myChatBot.sln /t:Rebuild/p:Configuration=Debug/p:Platform="any cpu"", does it turns any errors?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has made the code for msbuild tool open source. Have a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/SdkResolution/DefaultSdkResolver.cs) at the implementation for the DefaultSdkResolver.

You can see the path whose message "Illegal characters in path" refers to, is created the following way:

```
var sdkPath = Path.Combine(BuildEnvironmentHelper.Instance.MSBuildSDKsPath, sdk.Name, "Sdk");
```

First make sure you have at least one version of ".NET Core SDK" installed. If you do, and if you used the default installation folder, you should have something in the folder:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks   (adjust 3.1.101 to the version you have)

This folder will be the first argument for method Path.Combine. I don't understand why msbuild doesn't look for it in the default installation location, but it seems like you have to set a system variable to tell msbuild where are your SDKs.

**Variable name:** MSBuildSDKsPath 
**Variable value:** C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\

This variable will used for provide the value for BuildEnvironmentHelper.Instance.MSBuildSDKsPath

**VERY IMPORTANT:** Don't use quotes in the variable value and finish it with a "\", because, as you can see in source code, this value will be concatenated with the remaining path parts.

This should be enough for you to compile your code. If more problems, try to set the verbosity level to diagnostic and check the variable value on the beginning of the log. (add param *-v diag* when calling msbuild)

Answer (score 2):

> Any thoughts on why the SDK resolver
>   "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run ? How can I fix
>   this ?

**Illegal characters in path** often means that some paths like `%MEMORY_TRANSLATION%`,`%BUILDID%`,`%LOGFILE_TRANSLATION%` has **some illegal, unrecognized strings or incorrect formats**.

So please check these system variables and make sure that they can access successfully and l doubt the error is due to this.

**Besdies**, when you use MSBuild, please make sure that you have installed `Net Core`, `ASP.Net and web development` and `.Net Core cross-platform development` are installed in VS Installer.

[image]

[image]

**In addition**, you can use `msbuild xxxx.sln -t:rebuild` to build your project directly to test it is whether the issue of fortify scan or build process.

**Note** that you should first enter the path where the `myChatBot.sln` exists by using `cd xxxx(path)` and then use `msbuild myChatBot.sln -t:rebuild`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error with Visual Studio 2019 . I checked my *path* System variable and removed quote marks (") anywhere I found them.  This solved the problem.  (I also moved the path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` to the first entry in the *path* System variable, but I don't think that made any difference.)

It seems that some of the .NET utilities now consider quote marks as illegal path characters, for example: [Quote " characters in PATH cause "Illegal characters in path" failure in nuget restore](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8168)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the comment at the top of the SdkResolver class [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/SdkResolution/DefaultSdkResolver.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Default SDK resolver for compatibility with VS2017 RTM.
    /// <remarks>
    ///     Default Sdk folder will to:
    ///         1) MSBuildSDKsPath environment variable if defined
    ///         2) When in Visual Studio, (VSRoot)\MSBuild\Sdks\
    ///         3) Outside of Visual Studio (MSBuild Root)\Sdks\
    /// </remarks>
    /// </summary>
```

The following worked for me:

1- Copy the content of the Sdks folder here "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5\Sdks" (replace with your version number)

2- Paste here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional_Pre\MSBuild\Sdks" (replace with your visual studio version)

I don't really know why it works in this mysterious way.